# This function doesn't work correctly in some directories

Tags: c

This function should show list of files in directory but,
it works only in C:\Users\"name"\Desktop 
in other directories shows (directory) in all names
I've tried other ways but only this is working (somehow)

```
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <dirent.h>
# include <sys/types.h>
# include <stdio.h> 
   int list(){
        char s[50];
        struct dirent *entry;
        printf("Specify directory for list of files\n");
        scanf("%s", &s);
        DIR *dir = opendir(s);
        FILE* ff;
        if (dir){
                printf("\n\n******\n\n");
                while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
                ff = (fopen(entry->d_name, "r"));

                if (ff != NULL){
                    printf("%s\n",entry->d_name);
                    fclose(ff); 
                }
                else if (ff == NULL) {
                printf("%s(directory)\n",entry->d_name);
                }

            }
            printf("\n******\n");
            closedir(dir);
            return 1;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you examine the contents of `entry->d_name` you'll see that it only contains the filename and not the full path. So when you try and open the file, it can't unless the file exists in the current directory. You need to build the full path and use that to open the file.

```
char fullname[1024];
strcpy(fullname,s);
strcat(fullname,"\\");
strcat(fullname,entry->d_name);
ff = fopen(fullname, "r");
```

Comment: Change `1024` to `PATH_MAX` - see `limits.h`

Comment: @EdHeal weirdly, that no longer works and it looks like we're meant to use `pathconf` to find that value

Comment: Right - deleted comment.